# Making a call to API redirects me to Home with 302 status code

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have this following controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Book;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BookController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $books = $user->books;
        return response()->json(['books' => $books]);
    }
}
```

and its API router is

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('books', BookController::class);
});
```

and finally in my **Books.vue** I am trying to get the json response using `router` like this

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Head, router, Link } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
router.get('/api/books', { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' } })
// router.get('/api/books')
// axios.get('/api/books')
</script>
```

in the **Network** the result is

[image]

and then I am redirected to home page or login page if I am not logged in

a solution I read was to remove `return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);` from `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` but it only made it redirect to login despite being logged in

The only time it works is when I comment out the `auth:sanctum` middleware and make the controller use `$books = Book::all();`

Comment: Maybe I'm misremembering, but does Sanctum require/use Authorization Tokens? You're only sending the `Accept` header, so `auth()->user()` would be `null`. Not sure why it would think an `HTTP 302 Redirect` would be the correct status for an API call, should be 401 or 403 (one of the Unauthorized/Forbidden) statuses, but likely culprit is `middleware('auth:sanctum')`.

Comment: `middleware('auth:sanctum')` means this route can only be accessed by logged-in users. It's doing what you told it to do.

Comment: as I understand now it was because the requests aren't stateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by uncommenting this middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

`\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,`

according to https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#sanctum-middleware